# Concatenate all values in Select of Antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an application with a select. I want to concatenate all values from select if I saved many times the select value.

For example, if I chose fruit, after that another one and so one I want to have all values, not to override each time the previous value like now.

```js
const OPTIONS = ["Apples", "Nails", "Bananas", "Helicopters"];

class SelectWithHiddenSelectedOptions extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedItems: []
  };

  handleChange = selectedItems => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
  };
  save = () => {
    console.log(this.state.selectedItems);  // here i want to concatenate all values
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;
    const filteredOptions = OPTIONS.filter(o => !selectedItems.includes(o));
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          placeholder="Inserted are removed"
          value={selectedItems}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
        >
          {filteredOptions.map(item => (
            <Select.Option key={item} value={item}>
              {item}
            </Select.Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
        <button onClick={this.save}>click</button>
        <h1>{this.selectedItems}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How to achieve this?
link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-already-selected-ant-design-demo-46ojt

Comment: You mean multiselect like here https://codesandbox.io/s/3k3vjplo5 ??

Comment: @Maniraj Murugan, no, i want to do this with single select. It is possible?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, i want something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hamilton-go4m3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a prop **mode** with value `multiple` would work

Refer to [Ant Select document](https://ant.design/components/select/)

> mode
>   Set mode of Select
>   Type: multiple | tags
>
> value
>   Current selected option.
>   Type: string|string[],  number|number[],  LabeledValue|LabeledValue[]

```
<Select
  mode='multiple'
  ...
/>
```

[image]

[image: Edit Hide Already Selected - Ant Design Demo]

Comment: i want singe select.

Comment: i want something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hamilton-go4m3

Comment: @Asking Thanks for your feedback. I've noticed that post from you, handling.

Comment: @Asking The related post has been answered, kindly check it would be appreciated.

Comment: could you take a look, please stackoverflow.com/questions/62709476/… – Asking just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574664/cant-download-a-file-in-reactjs